# Как правильно реализовать функцию сортировки таблицы QTableWidget PyQt5 для числовых значений?

Tags: python, pyqt5, сортировка

```
def Sort(self):
    indCB = self.comboBox.currentIndex() # получение индекса выбранного параметра ComboBox
    if indCB == 1 or indCB == 2 or indCB == 6: # индексы числовых параметров ComboBox
        column_index = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().logicalIndex(indCB - 1) # индекс столбика с числовым значением
        for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            item = self.tableWidget.item(row, column_index) # получение значения из ячейки
            item_int = int(item.text()) # переводим в целочисленное значение
            item.setData(QtCore.Qt.EditRole, item_int) # присваеваем новое значение старому  
        self.tableWidget.sortItems(column_index) # сортируем с помощью встроенной функции

    if indCB == 3 or indCB == 4 or indCB == 5: # дальнейший код работает с текстовыми значениями и, соответственно, работает корректно
        column_index = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().logicalIndex(indCB - 1)
        self.tableWidget.sortItems(column_index, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
```

Comment: приведите воспроизводимый пример. По вашему коду надо еще гадать что есть что